# Why AdMob Adaptive banner ad is crashing?

Tags: android, admob, ads

I have replaced my smart banner ads with adaptive banner ads. But now, it is crashing on a few devices.

Here is the xml part:

```xml
<FrameLayout xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
</FrameLayout>
```

The Java part:

```java
MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
     @Override
     public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) { }
});
mAdView = new AdView(this);
mAdView.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.ad_unit_id));
adContainer.addView(mAdView);
loadBanner();
```

The loadBanner function:

```java
private AdSize getAdSize() {
    // Step 2 - Determine the screen width (less decorations) to use for the ad width.
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    DisplayMetrics outMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    display.getMetrics(outMetrics);

    float widthPixels = outMetrics.widthPixels;
    float density = outMetrics.density;

    int adWidth = (int) (widthPixels / density);

    // Step 3 - Get adaptive ad size and return for setting on the ad view.
    return AdSize.getCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSize(this, adWidth);
}
private void loadBanner() {
    // Create an ad request. Check your logcat output for the hashed device ID
    // to get test ads on a physical device, e.g.,
    // "Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("ABCDE0123") to get test ads on this
    // device."
    AdRequest adRequest =
            new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("ASKDJALDSKJALD")
                    .build();

    AdSize adSize = getAdSize();
    // Step 4 - Set the adaptive ad size on the ad view.
    mAdView.setAdSize(adSize);
    // Step 5 - Start loading the ad in the background.
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);  //****Crashing on this line****
}
```

It is crashing on `mAdView.loadAd(adRequest)`.

I looked up to the crash logs and they are:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException:
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2976)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3113)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute (LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:113)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:71)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1858)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:201)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6820)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:547)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:922)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzyq.zza (zzyq.java:82)
at com.google.android.gms.ads.BaseAdView.loadAd (BaseAdView.java:15)
at com.jazibkhan.equalizer.ui.activities.MainActivity.loadBanner (MainActivity.java:309)
at com.jazibkhan.equalizer.ui.activities.MainActivity.onCreate (MainActivity.java:341)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:7224)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:7213)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1272)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2956)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3113)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute (LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks
(TransactionExecutor.java:113)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:71)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1858)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:201)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6820)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:547)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:922)
```

I've done exactly what is shown in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner/adaptive) of the adaptive ads, but still getting crashes on a few devices.

Comment: adContainerView = findViewById(R.id.ad_view_container); is this code added before your load ad?

Comment: @AmodGokhale Yes, it's only crashing on few devices.

Comment: Can you also check if meta-data tag is added in manifest file and play services library and your ad library are compatible

Comment: Yes, everything is correct.